# последовательность основных шагов которые выполняет загрузчик классов

Tags: java, android

Вот написал я класс, он наследуется, к нему подключен интерфейс, в нем объявлены переменные и статик переменные, есть блок static , конструктор . Мне нужно узнать в какой последовательно всё это выполняется. А нужно это что бы понимать вот такие вещи: есть два класса, класс А в конструкторе инициализирует статическую переменную, которая есть в классе B , но класс B еще не отрабатывал ни разу, на класс B мы попадем только когда я кликну на кнопку и сработает Intent или еще по какой нибудь другой причине. Вот будет ли мне доступна эта статическая переменная

Comment: https://github.com/Javer-com-ua/WIKI/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-Java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Копипаста отсюда](https://github.com/Javer-com-ua/WIKI/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-Java)

Для случая наследования класов:

`public class Child extends Parent`
поля объекта инициализируются в следующем порядке:

1. Статические поля класса `Parent`
2. Статический блок инициализации класса `Parent`
3. Статические поля класса `Сhild`
4. Статический блок инициализации класса `Child`
5. Нестатические поля  класса `Parent`
6. Нестатический блок инициализации класса `Parent`
7. Конструктор класса `Parent`
8. Нестатические поля  класса `Сhild`
9. Нестатический блок инициализации класса `Сhild`
10. Конструктор класса `Сhild`

Comment: спасибо , то что нужно. А как выглядит нестатический блок инициализации ?

Comment: @Turalllb так же как и статический, только без слова `static`  в начале. Т.е. просто фигурные скобки `class MyClass{String s; {s="some_string"}}`. Лайфхак - в этом блоке можно исполнять код.